# Arranging divs in parallel in a sub menu

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to create a menu with a ul list as main menu and a collection of divs as sub menu, the HTML and CSS is as follows,

---

```
<ul>
    <li><a>AAAAAA</a>
        <div class="m-div group">
            <div class="child">
                <a>ITEM One</a><br />
                <a>ITEM One</a><br />
                <a>ITEM One</a><br />
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                <a>ITEM Two</a><br />
                <a>ITEM Two</a><br />
                <a>ITEM Two</a><br />
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                <a>ITEM Three</a><br />
                <a>ITEM Three</a><br />
                <a>ITEM Three</a><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a>BBBBBBB</a></li>
    <li><a>CCCCCCC</a></li>
    <li><a>DDDDDDD</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
* {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    ul {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

        ul li {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

    .m-div {
        background-color: lightgray;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .child {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
    }
```

---

But this code renders the menu as,

[image]

I need the sub menu to appear side by side as,

[image]

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: u want this submenu on hover or static one

Comment: Im trying to make the sub-menu's width expand dynamically as and when the number of sub menu divs increase with out setting a fixed width. Is this possible?

Comment: The sub menu should hover. The hover works fine. That's y i did not include that code here. Im trying to fix the styling issue of the sub menu divs.

Comment: u can use width as 100% and height as auto it will be auto increamenting

Comment: In this context applying a with of 100% doses not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check here for [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x4g9v/)

You have to give div `group`

```
.m-div {
        background-color: lightgray;
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yup.. That would do the trick! But im trying to make the menu expand dynamically as and when the number of sub menu divs increase. Is this possible?

Comment: @AJ_SHEHAN You can give dynamic height and width to `.m-div` using jquery or javascript

Comment: Yha Thanks. But I was trying to avoid that too. Provided the developer only the task of adding a new set of divs and applying the classes to them and not worry about changing the CSS.

Answer (score 4):

put width for m-div

```
 .m-div {
        background-color: lightgray;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
    width:400px;
    }

    .child {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98EdQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. The only way seems to be to add an explicit width to the sub menus parent div.